# NSLog returns (null) when logging string from another view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I posted a question earlier about the same thing, but now I have made a simple project to show what I am doing, so the problem can be found easier.

I have two viewControllers, one is called ViewController and the other SecondViewController.
I tried sending a NSString called testy to a viewController and logging it, but it returned null.

Here is my code trying to send the string from viewController to secondViewController

## ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize cellName;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    cellName = @"testy";

    SecondViewController *obj = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];

    obj.cellName2 = self.cellName;    
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

## ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

}
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *cellName;

@end
```

---

## SecondViewController.m

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

@synthesize cellName2;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
NSLog(@"%@",cellName2);

}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

## SecondViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController {

}

@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *cellName2;

@end
```

---

## Edit

I would like to say that my storyboard has two viewController that each have a button. Each button modally brings you to the other view.

Comment: Have you tried to add a breakpoint and look at the variables and properties involved? And if so, what did you see?

Comment: dont know how to use those

Comment: Are you using ARC? If so, you should be using `strong` instead of `retain`. If not, you should be sending `autorelease` when you initialize `SecondViewController *obj`.

Comment: Same results as before

Comment: @user2660874 The debugger is a very valuable tool for this sort of problem, so worth looking into. Anyway, the reason I asked is that in 99% of the cases a bug like this is an uninitialized variable. Easy to find with the debugger. And I prefer you spend a minute with the debugger before I have to spend 5 minutes reading all your code :-)

Comment: In your `viewDidLoad` of your 1st vc, your `obj` object (very descriptive name) vanishes when that method is done. Create a property to access it later.

Comment: How is this done? And thanks, I took me days to come up with `obj`

Comment: Yeah time spent learning to use the debugger with not be wasted time

Comment: I will definaitely look into it, do you know of a good tut for it?

Comment: What do you mean by "I tried sending a NSString called testy to a viewController and logging it, but it returned null."? You have message in a log, but with empty string? Or you have clear log?

Comment: sorry for any confusion, the log says (null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be worth for all who read this article to mention working patterns passing variables between two views:

Options:

1. Use global variable: [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17958944/pass-core-data-entity-variable-between-views/17959309#17959309)
2. Use delegation pattern: [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696304/passing-values-from-second-view-to-firstview-in-xcode)
3. Use notification infrastructure: [article](http://cupsofcocoa.com/2011/09/10/design-patterns-key-value-observing/)
4. Persist the value in app's userdefault storage, then read when you need : [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475300/storing-results-after-screen-is-disappear/16476022#16476022)

For this particular situation it might be better not to create secondviewcontroller in the firstviewcontroller's viewdidload, but to keep the cellName until that point when a user action happens (eg. button press) and then in that method you just set the newly created secondviewcontroller's cellName2 property.

```
SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"second" bundle:nil];
secondViewController.cellName = self.cellName;
```

I've tested and it is properly logging the value in secondviewcontroller's viewdidload.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure viewDidLoad is being called? I think it's not called until the view is loaded. I don't think it's called after an alloc init. **Also you are setting the string in obj 2 after init. Even if what you are thinking is correct, the 'viewDidLoad' method may be called before the string is being set.**

**If you want a variable set on init you need to override viewController 2's init method to something like initWithMyVariable** then the var will be set on init.

From: [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Passing data forward to a view controller from another view controller. You would use this method if you wanted to pass an object/value from one view controller to another view controller that you may be pushing on to a navigation stack.

For this example we will have ViewControllerA and ViewControllerB

To pass a BOOL value from ViewControllerA to ViewControllerB we would do the following.

in ViewControllerB.h create a property for the BOOL

```
@property(nonatomic) BOOL *isSomethingEnabled;
```

in ViewControllerA you need to tell it about ViewControllerB so use an

## import "ViewControllerB.h"

Then where you want to load the view eg. didSelectRowAtIndex or some IBAction you need to set the property in ViewControllerB before you push it onto nav stack.

```
ViewControllerB *viewControllerB = [[ViewControllerB alloc] initWithNib:@"ViewControllerB" bundle:nil];
viewControllerB.isSomethingEnabled = YES;
[self pushViewController:viewControllerB animated:YES];
```

This will set isSomethingEnabled in ViewControllerB to BOOL value YES.

Comment: Im sure it is, because if I put nsLog "hello world" it logs it

Comment: Its definitely not called by alloc/init. The view has to be displayed somehow.

Comment: @user2660874 where do you push/present your second viewController?

Comment: You don't. Add `[self presentViewController: obj animated: YES completion: nil];` at the end of your first viewControllers viewDidLoad. And also, change `cellName = @"testy";` to `self.cellName = @"testy";`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing:  `cellName = @"testy";`   You should Call:

```
 self.cellName = @"testy";
```

Also, When you `alloc` and `init` in:

`SecondViewController *obj = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];`,
 the `viewDidLoad()` for secondViewController is called right at that time and you are initializing it's iVar later in the line `obj.cellName2 = self.cellName;`

That's why you are having NSLOG as null.

Print the NSLOG in viewWillAppear() of secondViewController and you will see the right value this time.

Comment: Or you can also @synthesize cellName to ommit the self part

Comment: @user2660874: "@synthesize" cellName2 in SecondViewController.m

Comment: same results as before

Comment: @Jamal Do you think it could be a way my storyboard is set up?

Comment: @user2660874: also shift your initialization code in viewWillAppear() instead of viewDidLoad()

Comment: I tried out this and really works for me.. I think the problem is that you want to create a second viewcontroller in the fist's viewdidload which for me makes no sense. You can save the string var in firstview until a user action happens (like click on button/table cell) then you switch to second view which is the right time to make the variable assignment. The assignment itself is ok, it should work and you an also read out in secondviewcontroller's viewdidload too.

Comment: See my updated question, is that waht you were talking about?

Comment: @user2660874: synthesize" cellName2 in SecondViewController.m

Comment: @user2660874: and print the cellName2 in NSLog as "self.cellName2"

Comment: @user2660874: have you placed the code of NSLOG in viewWillAppear() in secondViewcontroller.m?

Answer (score 0):

-Create a initialization method for second view controller to pass the variable..

in secondview controller 
.h file

add init method

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil cellString(NSString* )cellName;
```

and .m file

```
-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil cellString(NSString* )cellName{

   self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

     if (self) {

        // Custom initialization
     cellName2=cellName;

     }
     return self;

}
```

and in ViewController.m for initialization

```
SecondViewController *obj = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil cellString:self.cellName];
```

This should work...
Best of luck

Comment: three errors No visible @interface for 'SecondViewController' declares the selector 'initWithNibName:bundle:cellString:'

Comment: Expected ':' and Expected ';' after method prototype

Comment: you should paste this code in .h file  this is a custom init method   - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil cellString(NSString* )cellName;

Comment: are you using interface builder for your project.

Answer (score -1):

In viewcontroller.m you have the following in viewDidLoad:

```
..
..
SecondViewController *obj = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
obj.cellName2 = self.cellName;    
}
```

The SecondViewController "obj" is never being presented before the end of viewDidLoad, hence NSLog printing null.

If you are wanting to pass a value to SecondViewController via a storyboard, you will need to use the **prepareForSegue** method.  A good example of using it can be found [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2).